# Codeception Gherkin, defining the step implementation path

Tags: php, phpunit, bdd, codeception, behat

I’m new to php and codeception and I wanted to use Gherkin with Codeception, and I’ve already setup the bare minimum to make feature files run in Codeception. I now find myself trying to make a scalable structure and make use of the PageObject framework. I created a **Steps** Folder and I wanted my step implementations kept in that folder. By default running `codecept run some.feature` loads the class defined in the `acceptance.suite.yml` file.

**Motivation:** I want to be able keep my step implementations into it’s own separate folder

**Given** I have an acceptance.suite.yml file configuration of:

```
gherkin:
    contexts:
        default: 
            - AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: https://www.google.com/
            browser: chrome
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

**And** I have a `codeception.yml` file configuration of:

```
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
```

**And** I have my **Steps** folder under `_support`:

[image]

> How do I change the configuration to allow my step implementation to be
>   called from the Steps folder?

Comment: I never trying `PageObject` in codeception, but for dealing with repetitive code in I use `StepObject` in my test. http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#StepObjects

Answer (score 3):

In the `gherkin:` section of the suite configuration, you need to list your steps classes organised under `default:`, `role:` and/or `tag:` sections. There are example configurations in the official documentation: [Gherkin options](https://codeception.com/docs/07-BDD#Configuration).

Below is an example from a recent project (using Codeception 2.5.6):

**file structure**

```
/app/common
├── codeception.yml
├── tests
│   ├── acceptance.suite.yml
│   ├── _bootstrap.php
│   ├── _data
│   │   └── user.php
│   ├── _support
│   │   ├── AcceptanceTester.php
│   │   ├── Step
│   │   │   └── Acceptance
│   │   │       └── CuratorSteps.php
```

> The layout above for the step class is the default one when generating step object using codecept `generate:stepobject` command like so:
>
> ```
> $ /app/vendor/bin/codecept -c /app/common generate:stepobject acceptance CuratorSteps
> ```

**acceptance.suite.yml:**

```
# acceptance.suite.yml
namespace: common\tests
suite_namespace: common\tests\acceptance
bootstrap: false
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://example.com/
gherkin:
    contexts:
        default:
            - common\tests\AcceptanceTester
        role:
            curator:
                - common\tests\Step\Acceptance\CuratorSteps
```

> The documentation doesn't mention it, but I notice I have to list the full namespace of the step classes, otherwise I'll get **"Step definition for ... not found in contexts"** errors when running the tests and the `gherkin:steps` codecept command won't return the step definitions.

**output**

```
$ /app/vendor/bin/codecept -vvv -c /app/common gherkin:steps acceptance
Steps from role:curator context:
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Step                                                               | Implementation                                                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| I sign in as an admin                                              | common\tests\Step\Acceptance\CuratorSteps::iSignInAsAnAdmin                              |
| I should see a :arg1 button                                        | common\tests\Step\Acceptance\CuratorSteps::iShouldSeeAButton                             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Steps from default context:
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Step                                | Implementation                                          |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| I take a screenshot with name :arg1 | common\tests\AcceptanceTester::itakeAScreenshotWithName |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```